# How do I tell ELMAH that its DB objects reside under a new schema?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, web-config, elmah

We have an MVC application that utilizes the ELMAH module to log any errors that are encountered by our users.

Our DBAs have moved our ELMAH table and stored procedure into a new schema on a database. So now, the default ELMAH pages are failing to access the ELMAH stored procedures and tables since they reside under 'Foo.ELMAH_Error', instead of just 'ELMAH_Error'.

Is there any way to tell the ELMAH module that the table now exists in a new schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I got this to work by creating a new user for who has full access to the ELMAH procs & tables. I set the default database for the user to the new schema.

This solution appears to work well.

Answer (score 1):

You can create synonyms for ELMAH related objects as follows:
Following is for SQL Server. You can apply similar changes if you are using any other databases but may need some changes to syntax.

```
Create synonym ELMAH_Error for [YourSchema].ELMAH_Error;
Create synonym ELMAH_GetErrorsXml for [YourSchema].ELMAH_GetErrorsXml;
Create synonym ELMAH_GetErrorXml for [YourSchema].ELMAH_GetErrorXml;
Create synonym ELMAH_LogError for [YourSchema].ELMAH_LogError;
```

After this, ELMAH log to sql will work as usual.